# Create a dataframe of Max and Min Values between comparisons of the different levels of a variable using R and tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Using this example dataset

```
library(tidyverse)

data_set <-
  data.frame(
    var1 = rep(c("N", “N", "Y", "Y"), each = 2),
    var2 = rep(c("UnExp", "Exp", "UnExp", "Exp"), each = 2),
    x = rnorm(8),
    y = rnorm(8),
    z = rnorm(8)
  )


data_set <- data_set %>%
  unite("grp", var1:var2, sep = ".", remove = FALSE)
```

Using a tidy workflow that minimizes creation of unnecessary intermediate objects I want to get a dataframe that contains a column with the 6 comparisons possible between the levels of `grp`, the names of the variables `x`, `y` and `z` as well as the maximum and minimum value for these variables between the comparisons of `grp`. In other words, a dataframe like this

```
R > head(output.df,13)
        Comparison    name    max      min
1    N.UnExp-N.Exp    x     max.x1   min.x1
2  N.UnExp-Y.UnExp    x     max.x2   min.x2
3    N.UNExp-Y.Exp    x     max.x3   min.x3
4    N.Exp-Y.UnExp    x     max.x4   min.x4
5      N.Exp-Y.Exp    x     max.x5   min.x5
6    Y.UnExp-Y.Exp    x     max.x6   min.x6
7    N.UnExp-N.Exp    y     max.y1   min.y1
8  N.UnExp-Y.UnExp    y     max.y2   min.y2
9    N.UNExp-Y.Exp    y     max.y3   min.y3
10   N.Exp-Y.UnExp    y     max.y4   min.y4
11     N.Exp-Y.Exp    y     max.y5   min.y5
12   Y.UnExp-Y.Exp    y     max.y6   min.y6
13   N.UnExp-N.Exp    z     max.z1   min.z1
```

I have tried using `summarize_if` but I am unable to get quite what I am looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your `data_set` correct? 4 rows of N.UnExp and 4 rows of Y.Exp. Also why would you expect differing number of comparisons for each variable, when you data_set has the same number of observations and grps for each of x y and z?

Comment: I have pasted only the first 13 rows of ```output.df```. There are 5 more rows, making it 6 comparisons for each of the 3 variables in the data.

Comment: I have corrected the data regarding the error you pointed out in your comment. Thanks.

Comment: I don't completely follow. Can you create the data using `set.seed` and show expected output with values so that it would be easier to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution as you don't have the actual values so not sure if this really what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(100) # Ensure random generate same value for every run

# This part is your code
data_set <-
  data.frame(
    var1 = rep(c("N", "N", "Y", "Y"), each = 2),
    var2 = rep(c("UnExp", "Exp", "UnExp", "Exp"), each = 2),
    x = rnorm(8),
    y = rnorm(8),
    z = rnorm(8)
  )
data_set <- data_set %>%
  unite("grp", var1:var2, sep = ".", remove = FALSE)

# First pivot it into a long table with x,y,z is name column
# their value in value column
group_summarize <- data_set %>%
  group_by(grp, var1, var2) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("x", "y", "z"), names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>%
  ungroup()

# Generate all avaialble comparison pair and put then into a tibble
pair_comparision <- as_tibble(t(combn(unique(group_summarize[["grp"]]), m = 2)))
names(pair_comparision) <- c("grp_1", "grp_2")

# convert all grp variable to factor and preserve the orders provided by original data
group_summarize$grp <- factor(group_summarize$grp,
                              levels = unique(group_summarize$grp))
pair_comparision$grp_1 <- factor(pair_comparision$grp_1,
                                 levels = unique(group_summarize$grp))
pair_comparision$grp_2 <- factor(pair_comparision$grp_2,
                                 levels = unique(group_summarize$grp))
# Do t he comparison 
pair_comparision %>%
  # Name of comparision by combine grp_1 & grp_2
  mutate(Comparison = paste0(grp_1, " - ", grp_2)) %>%
  # Join with the pivot long table for getting all value from 1st grp.
  left_join(group_summarize %>% select(grp, name, value_1 = value),
            by = c("grp_1" = "grp")) %>%
  # Join with the pivot long table for getting all values corresponded to
  # 2nd grp and name (x, y, z).
  left_join(group_summarize %>% select(grp, name, value_2 = value),
            by = c("grp_2" = "grp", "name" = "name")) %>%
  # Do the comparision within each comparision
  group_by(grp_1, grp_2, Comparison, name) %>%
  summarize(max = max(value_1, value_2), min = min(value_1, value_2),
            .groups = "drop") %>%
  # arrange the data by name (x, y, z) and factor order of group
  arrange(name, grp_1, grp_2)
```

Here is the output

```
# A tibble: 18 x 6
   grp_1   grp_2   Comparison        name     max     min
   <fct>   <fct>   <chr>             <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 N.UnExp N.Exp   N.UnExp - N.Exp   x     0.887  -0.502 
 2 N.UnExp Y.UnExp N.UnExp - Y.UnExp x     0.319  -0.502 
 3 N.UnExp Y.Exp   N.UnExp - Y.Exp   x     0.715  -0.582 
 4 N.Exp   Y.UnExp N.Exp - Y.UnExp   x     0.887  -0.0789
 5 N.Exp   Y.Exp   N.Exp - Y.Exp     x     0.887  -0.582 
 6 Y.UnExp Y.Exp   Y.UnExp - Y.Exp   x     0.715  -0.582 
 7 N.UnExp N.Exp   N.UnExp - N.Exp   y     0.0963 -0.825 
 8 N.UnExp Y.UnExp N.UnExp - Y.UnExp y     0.740  -0.825 
 9 N.UnExp Y.Exp   N.UnExp - Y.Exp   y     0.123  -0.825 
10 N.Exp   Y.UnExp N.Exp - Y.UnExp   y     0.740  -0.202 
11 N.Exp   Y.Exp   N.Exp - Y.Exp     y     0.123  -0.0293
12 Y.UnExp Y.Exp   Y.UnExp - Y.Exp   y     0.740  -0.202 
13 N.UnExp N.Exp   N.UnExp - N.Exp   z     2.31   -0.914 
14 N.UnExp Y.UnExp N.UnExp - Y.UnExp z     0.764  -0.438 
15 N.UnExp Y.Exp   N.UnExp - Y.Exp   z     0.773  -0.389 
16 N.Exp   Y.UnExp N.Exp - Y.UnExp   z     2.31   -0.914 
17 N.Exp   Y.Exp   N.Exp - Y.Exp     z     2.31   -0.914 
18 Y.UnExp Y.Exp   Y.UnExp - Y.Exp   z     0.773  -0.438
```

[**Update: using factor and arrange to sort the final output in certain order]**

Comment: Yes. This is almost exactly what I want. I wanted two columns that had the ```max``` and ```min``` values of variables ```x```, ```y``` and ```z``` between each possible combination of 2 levels of the total 6 available levels from ```grp```.

Comment: I do have one issue with the solution above. Is there a simple way to arrange the rows in the order I specified? I mean ```Comparison``` needs to have N.UnExp-N.Exp first, and all comparisons of ```x``` to be in the first 6 rows? I could probably copy it to a csv and reorder it, but would like to have a  way to do this within R. Many thanks. Edit: The earlier comment should have said ... 4 levels of ```grp```, not 6.

Comment: I updated the answers as your feedback! May you see if it matched. Hope the detail in-line comment which describe details of what each line of code help you understand the code better and tweak further base on your actual use-case.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. I have accepted this answer.